# the evening news vs evening news

Tags: articles

Are correct both examples? If it is so, what is the difference? If it is not correct, why?

> Ann turned on the television to watch **the evening news**.

vs

> Ann turned on the television to watch **evening news**.

Comment: The first version is idiomatic, because Ann was presumably intending to watch a regular news bulletin scheduled at a particular time. 'Evening news' without an article would be a vague general reference to news broadcast during the evening.